# Formatting the year in biblatex bibliograpy driver (.bbx) files

Tags: biblatex

Normally, to set the format of a field using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), the `\DeclareFieldFormat` macro can be used, for example

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

However, this approach fails for the year. Trying either

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\mkbibbobld{#1}}
```

or

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

Makes no difference to the output. You can do something like

```
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\mkbibbold{\printdate}}
```

to format the date, but this looses the link to bibliography entry type and thus requires more work for type-dependent appearance. Is there a better approach, ideally sticking to `\DeclareFieldFormat`?

Comment: I think this doesn't work because dates are printed with the `\printdate` command and not the `\printfield` command.

Comment: @Alan: Yes, that is my take, but then there is no `\DeclareDateFormat`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:**

Today (14 nov) biblatex v 1.7 is available. In the new version special field formats `date`, `urldate`, `origdate`, `eventdate` were added.

---

When you redefine the bibmacro `date` in the following way you can use such a definition:

```
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printtext[date]{\printdate}}
```

The following example shows the result

```
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{book1,
 Author = {Vorname Nachname},
 Date = {1998},
 Publisher = {Verlag},
 Title = {Der Mythos},
 urldate={2002-06-02}
}
@book{book2,
 Author = {Hans Nachname},
 Date = {2001-07-08},
 Publisher = {Verlag},
 Title = {Der Mythos},
 urldate={2002-06-02}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\textbf{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printtext[date]{\printdate}}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}

text \cite{book1}

text \cite{book2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting approach - not one I'd thought of.

Comment: @Joseph: It the same trick as for `urldate`. The command `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}...` exists in `biblatex.def`. So I looked to the definition and than I used it :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Please see my updated answer. I think it could be interesting for you.